# Size of char *c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *c;

int main() {
    printf("size: %ld\n", sizeof(c));
    return 0;
}
```

output of the above program is size: 8, Trying to understand how char type take 8byte in 32-bit machine ?

Comment: first of all `c` is a pointer to `char` not a `char`

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, the size of a pointer is 8 bytes. What makes you so sure you have a 32-bit machine/program in 2023?

Comment: it's a pointer. Try sizeof(*c).

Comment: `c` is a `char*`, so `sizeof(c)` is `sizeof(char*)`. You're clearly not compiling for a 32-bit target.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. you are using `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: The result of `sizeof` has type `size_t`. Correct format specifier for `printf`is `%zu`, not `%ld`.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Answer (score -1):

In your code, the variable `c` declared as `char *c` is a pointer to `char`. The size of a pointer depends on the target architecture.

On a 32-bit (x86) architecture, the size of a pointer is typically 4 bytes. On a 64-bit (x64) architecture, the size of a pointer is typically 8 bytes.

Judging by your output, your target architecture is x64-based and not x86-based. If you do not manually specify the target architecture and your compiler is configured for your host OS, here's how to determine if your architecture is x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit):

On Windows, open the command prompt and type:

```
wmic os get osarchitecture
```

On Linux or Mac, open a terminal and type:

```
uname -m
```

Comment: the bitness of the OS has nothing to do with a program's bitness. A 32-bit program running on 64-bit OS obviously still has 32-bit pointer

Comment: @machine_1, The OS influences a compiler's reasonable choices, yet the pointer size in C is determined by the compiler, not the OS.

Comment: Right. I was assuming the program was being compiled for the host OS without choosing a particular configuration

Comment: @machine_1: Even if a program is to run directly on the same OS as the compiler, rather than in a virtual machine or other hardware, there are OSes that support multiple address sizes (e.g., can run either “32 bit” or “64 bit” processes). Further, a C compiler can be designed to produce programs that have 32 bit pointers because the entire program uses only 32 bits in each address even though the hardware supports 64. (I have used such a compiler.) The size of a pointer is determined by the C implementation, not the hardware or the operating system.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did say "_typically_" though, didn't I?